# What is required for a view menu item to show up as a link in the admin page?

Tags: views

I'm creating several views that are to be used as reports. Since they all have a common topic, I'm grouping the views under a sub-path of `admin/reports` (e.g. `admin/reports/data/needs_correction` and `admin/reports/data/status`).

With most admin sections in Drupal, there's usually a landing page that lists all of the sub-content for the section. So, to provide that, I've implemented `hook_menu()` in the feature that contains the exported report views, as follows:

```php
/**
 * Implements hook_menu().
 */
function MY_menu() {
  $items = array();

  $items['admin/reports/data'] = array(
    'title'             => 'Data reports',
    'description'       => 'Various reports on the status of data in the system.',
    'position'          => 'left',
    'page callback'     => 'system_admin_menu_block_page',
    'access arguments'  => array('access administration pages'),
    'file'              => 'system.admin.inc',
    'file path'         => drupal_get_path('module', 'system'),
  );

  return $items;
}
```

The only problem is that, after a cache clear, when I navigate to `admin/reports/data`, all I get is the message "You do not have any administrative items."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to the report views needing to have "Page" displays with URLs nested under `admin/reports/data`, I also had to make sure the following settings were enabled under "Page: Menu item entry" settings within the Views:

- **Type:** Normal menu entry
- **Menu:** Management

Without both of these settings, the menu links will *not* show up under the new custom reports page.